# How to find the characteristic polynomial of a $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What is the best strategy to find the characteristic polynomial of a 3x3 matrix?

For example I got this matrix:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}6 & -2 & -1 \\ -2 & 6 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$

and I know the characteristic equation of this matrix should be:
$ -\lambda^3 + 17\lambda^2 -90\lambda + 144 $ and that I can get it from solving $(6-\lambda)(6-\lambda)(5-\lambda)+something$ however the formula without $something$ solves to $-\lambda^3 + 17 \lambda^2 - 96\lambda + 180$. What should this $something$ be?

Alternatively, [this website](https://www.vcalc.com/equation/?uuid=1fe0a0b6-1ea2-11e6-9770-bc764e2038f2&viewer=code) says this formula exists:

> $−λ^3+tr(A)λ^2+(tr(A)^2−tr(A^2))λ+det(A)$

however, I find:

$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}41 & -23 &-9 \\ -23 & 41 & -9 \\ -9 & -9 & 27 \end{bmatrix}$

and thus $tr(A)^2−tr(A^2)=17^2-109=180$ which results in the equation $−λ^3+17λ^2+180λ+144$ which is not correct. Did I do something wrong here? Because if this formula does work it is very usefull

Comment: How about $\det (A-\lambda I)$?

Comment: I think that web site left out a factor of $\frac12$

Comment: The eigenvalues, and hence the characteristic polynomial, of this particular matrix can be found by inspection. That aside, I’m not convinced that using this formula (with the correct coefficients) is really any less work than simply computing $\det(A-\lambda I)$. Either way you have to compute a $3\times3$ determinant and to use the formula you also have to compute $A^2$.

Comment: @amd Although what you say is true I (for one) can't compute in my head determinants with polynomial entries: whereas I can usually compute in my head the trace of $A$, the sum of the principal $2\times 2$ minors of $A$, and the determinant of $A$. I agree that the expression for the coefficient of $\lambda$ is a needless complication.

Comment: that web site has been corrected (in response to my contacting them)

Comment: Nice, I hadn't thought of contacting them.

Comment: Here's what they wrote:  jwtanner,
   Thank you very much for pointing out the error on the Characteristic Polynomial for a 3x3 matrix page.  As it turns out, the factor is indeed buried in our calculations, but not displayed on the page correctly.   
   Thanks to you, it is now.  So, we have the right calculation and the right formula displayed.

If there's ever anything we can do for you, especially if you need other calculators, let us know.

Kurt
____________
Kurt Heckman
vCalc LLC
P.O. Box 632
McHenry, Md. 21541-0632
kurt@vcalc.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the matrix $A$, and you know that its characteristic polynomial should be $ -\lambda^3 + 17\lambda^2 -90\lambda + 144 ,$ but when you apply the formula listed at that web site, you get $−λ^3+17λ^2+\color{red}{180}λ+144$, which is not correct.  You wrote:

> Did I do something wrong here? Because if this formula does work it is very useful

You did not do anything wrong, but the formula listed on that web site left out a factor of $\frac12$, which should multiply the coefficient $tr(A)^2-tr(A^2)$ of $\lambda$.  Of note, that web site seems to calculate the characteristic polynomial correctly when the matrix components are entered.  Correct formulas for the characteristic polynomial of a $3\times3$ matrix, including $\frac12[tr(A)^2-tr(A^2)],$ are given on [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since asking this question I did some calculating. I like to share it. Hopefully it makes some sense...

For some reason finding the 2x2 minors never felt intuitive to me. I understand that it works but I don't understand what/why I do it.

For me row reducing feel more understandable. For example the $det(A)=ad-bc$:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d-\frac{c}{a}b \end{bmatrix}, det(A)=a(d-\frac{c}{a}b) =ad-bc $

and with the same method:

$B=\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix}\sim
\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ 0 & e-\frac{d}{a}b & f-\frac{d}{a}c \\ 0 & h-\frac{g}{a}b & i-\frac{g}{a}c  \end{bmatrix}\sim
\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ 0 & e-\frac{d}{a}b & f-\frac{d}{a}c \\ 0 & 0 & 
i-\frac{g}{a}c -\frac{h-\frac{g}{a}b}{ e-\frac{d}{a}b}(f-\frac{d}{a}c) \end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ 0 & e-\frac{d}{a}b & f-\frac{d}{a}c \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{a e i - a f h - b d i + b f g + c d h - c e g}{a e - b d} \end{bmatrix}$

this formula is found:

$ det(B)=a(e-\frac{d}{a}b)(\frac{a e i - a f h - b d i + b f g + c d h - c e g}{a e - b d}) =a e i - a f h - b d i + b f g + c d h - c e g $

I find it is easier to calculate the determinant using these six 'diagonals'.

When this method is used on $(B-λI)$

$C=\begin{bmatrix}a-λ & b & c \\ d & e-λ & f \\ g & h & i-λ \end{bmatrix}\sim
\begin{bmatrix}a-λ & b & c \\ 0 & (e-λ)-\frac{d}{a-λ}b & f-\frac{d}{a-λ}c \\ 0 & 0 & (i-λ)-\frac{g}{a-λ}c -\frac{h-\frac{g}{a-λ}b}{ (e-λ)-\frac{d}{a-λ}b}(f-\frac{d}{a-λ}c)  \end{bmatrix}$

$Det(C) = \frac{(a - λ) (e - λ) - bd}{(a - λ) (e - λ) - bd}-λ^3 + (a + e + i)λ^2 - (ae  + ai + ei )λ+(fh   + bd  + cg )λ+(aei + bfg + cdh - ceg - bdi- afh)$

meaning that the characterisitic polynomial can be written as:

- $-λ^3$
- $+tr(C)λ^2$
- $-$sum of products of all values on the 'main' diagonal.
- $+$sums of products of all values on the other diagonals.
- $+det(A)$

In my original case:

$-λ^3 + (6+6+5)λ^2 -(36+30+30)λ + (4+1+1)λ + (180-20-6-6-2-2)$

$=-λ^3 + 17λ^2 -90λ + 144$